# Azure App Configuration config reload to pick up changes

Tags: azure, service, config

We are looking to use Azure App Configuration Service in an event based system that will contain around 5 microservices (azure function Apps); and use Azure Event Grid and Azure Service Bus.

The system will grow to process about 50 billion messages annually.

Configurations will be contained in (1) standard app settings key value pairs; and number of json files with relatively complex objects. These files are stored as blobs in Azure storage.

Administrators will use a portal to make changes that will ultimately update configs relatively frequently. The applications will need to refresh their configs. The system cannot really be a candidate system for slot swapping given that configs will be changed via portal and not by way of CICD.

What I need help understanding is how to ensure all instances of scaled out function apps will be update.

Can all instance be updated only by implementing a polling strategy (polling from each instance of the functions); or can event grid be used where it is triggered by changes it is interested in (app config service or blob); and then event grid posts a message to a function which has logic to reload? For the latter scenario, how can I ensure all instances in the scaled out environment, pick up and run using latest configs.